# proper way to use delete in nested class

Tags: c++, class, delete-operator

I'm learning c++, and have a bit of a difficulty in grasping this aspect of memory management.
For my assignment I have to make a stack-like object(there might more efficient way to code this, but that doesn't bother me yet..)
I can't really tell if I am properly freeing the memory allocated by my objects:

```
template<typename dtp>
class cue{

class member{
member * next = NULL;
cue * parent;

public:
dtp data;
member(dtp d, cue * p)
{
    parent = p;
    data = d;
    if(parent->last == NULL){parent->first = this; parent->last = this;}
    else{parent->last->next = this; parent->last = this; }
}

~member(){
    cout<<"deleting entry: "<<data<<endl;
    parent->first = next; 
}
};

member * first = NULL;
member * last = NULL;

public:
int s=0;
dtp back(){return last->data;}
dtp front(){return first->data;}
bool empty(){if(s == 0) return true; else return false;}
int size(){return s;}

void push(dtp input){
    new member(input, this);
    s++;
}

void pop(){
    delete first;
    s--;
}

~cue(){
    cout<<"s="<<s<<endl;
    while(s > 0){
     this->pop();
    }
}   
};
```

I don't really understand if need the `delete this;` in the member's destructor (it should be fine to use otherwise since members can only be created by `cue.push()`).. Is `delete last;` enough.. Or maybe I'm totally wrong altogether?

Comment: That is a very odd way of creating a linked list. And no you don't delete all items in the list. And no you should not do `delete this` in a destructor.

Comment: `delete this;` in a destructor is always wrong, as `*this` is already in the process of being destroyed.

Comment: `new member(input, this);`  Who is going to deallocate this memory?  You called `new` without storing the return value anywhere so that a subsequent `delete` can be issued at some point.  And I agree with the previous comment -- this is a very odd way to create a linked list.

Comment: It's really unusual for the members to manage the list (stack). Normally the container manages its members, such that they are not even aware of which container they are stored in (if any).

Comment: Well apparently it's strange.. it kinda feels natural to me. The way it deletes it is starts with the last entry, and goes back via the pointer last, and each member holding a pointer to the previous one... What really concerns me is whether this gets the job done... (Also what are the downsides to my approach.. if it's only "odd" it doesn't bother me too much)

Comment: ok now i see why it was strange, i've updated my code, and it should be less strange now, although it still uses the same general structure. Since you delete elements from the beginning only anyways, there was no need to go in reverse in the destructor.